# Does triggers run in transaction in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Suppose I fire a delete command on Table A, and this A is being referred as FK on Table B, again B is FK for Table C.Every Table A,B,C has Delete triggers. 
Now If Any triggers fails in A,B,C does original Delete command Rollback.

Comment: Any reason for using delete triggers vs. `ON DELETE CASCADE` option on your foreign keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the trigger fails your transaction rolls back; also see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164032.aspx